# Merge tables having different columns (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database, join, merge, rdbms

I have 2 tables with details as follows

Table 1

```
Name | City | Employee_Id
-----------------
Raj  | CA   | A2345
Diya | IL   | A1234
Max  | PL   | A2321
Anna | TX   | A1222
Luke | DC   | A5643
```

Table 2

```
Name | City | Employee_Id | Phone | Age
---------------------------------------
Raj  | CA   | A2345       | 4094  | 25
Diya | IL   | A1234       | 4055  | 19
Max  | PL   | A2321       | 4076  | 23
```

As you can see, `Employee_Id` is the common column in both the columns. I want to update all the entries present in table 1 into table 2.

Raj, Divya and Max are already present in Table 2. So it should not create a duplicate entry in table 2 and skip those 3 entries whereas Anna and Luke are not present in table 2. so this should be added as a new row.

The SQL should be able to merge these 2 columns and ignore the rows which are already present. The final table 2 must be similar to this.

Table 2

```
Name | City | Employee_Id | Phone | Age
---------------------------------------
Raj  | CA   | A2345       | 4094  | 25
Diya | IL   | A1234       | 4055  | 19
Max  | PL   | A2321       | 4076  | 23
Anna | TX   | A1222       |       |   
Luke | DC   | A5643       |       |
```

Is there a way I could achieve this? I am pretty new to SQL, so any inputs would be of great help. I read about merge and update feature but I guess merge is in Transact-SQL. Also read about joins but could not find a way to crack this.

Comment: Sql Server or MySql ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza- sql server

Comment: How about `Raj / OH / A2345`? No moves or name changes allowed for with the same employee id? What you'd want is a duplicate employee id?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson- Employee_ID will be unique.. and this parameter needs to be checked before inserting in table2. if table2 has employee_id with A2345, it will not insert again...

Comment: What should it do if it finds the row mentioned above? Update the row with the correct data from table1 or just ignore the row from table1?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson- It should update the row then with whatever values present in table1 for that employee_id. i didnt notice of this test case. thank you so mucg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Name] varchar(4), [City] varchar(2), [Employee_Id] varchar(5));

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Name], [City], [Employee_Id])
VALUES
    ('Raj', 'FL', 'A2345'),
    ('Diya', 'IL', 'A1234'),
    ('Max', 'PL', 'A2321'),
    ('Anna', 'TX', 'A1222'),
    ('Luke', 'DC', 'A5643');

CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([Name] varchar(4), [City] varchar(2), [Employee_Id] varchar(5), [Phone] int, [Age] int);

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([Name], [City], [Employee_Id], [Phone], [Age])
VALUES
    ('Raj', 'CA', 'A2345', 4094, 25),
    ('Diya', 'IL', 'A1234', 4055, 19),
    ('Max', 'PL', 'A2321', 4076, 23);
```

**MERGE QUERY**

```
MERGE Table2 AS target
    USING Table1 AS source 
    ON (target.[Employee_Id] = source.[Employee_Id])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET [Name] = source.[Name],
                   [City] = source.[City]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([Name], [City], [Employee_Id], [Phone], [Age])
    VALUES (source.[Name], source.[City], source.[Employee_Id], NULL, NULL);

SELECT *
FROM Table2
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. 

I get the following error- Invalud column name 'name', invalid column name 'City' and so on

Comment: well did you give us the correct db schema? I just use this function sintaxis ... http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: does this query cover the test case mentioned by Joachim Isaksoon in the above comments ?

Comment: Nope this is only for Insert, you need a separated instruction for update. Let me check if there is a merge instruction

Comment: When we write this statement ----> INSERT INTO table2 values ---- shouldnt it only take values like "Raj" and so on rather than column names ?

Comment: Maybe i am getting an error because i am mentioning column names after values in the first line ?

Comment: Found a better way using `MERGE`. That way you handle the update and insert. There is also option for delete if you are interested https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/